# General error: 1364 Field 'StudentID' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel

im trying to make a simple formule that insert data to 2 different tables that have relationship hasMany but i keep getting this error:
1364 Field 'PlayerID' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `phones` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (qws, 2019-10-19 22:45:40, 2019-10-19 22:45:40))

here is player model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');


    }

}
```

phone model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class phone extends Model
{
    public function Player()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Player');


    }
}
```

this controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Player;
use App\phone;

class PlayersControlller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('players.create');    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $people = new Player();
        $phone = new phone();

        $people->name = $request->input('name');
        $people->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
        $phone->name =$request->input('pname');

        $phone->save();
        $people->save();    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and this is the form

```
 <form action="{{url('player')}}" method="Post" >

            {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label> name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <label>  last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <label> phone name</label>
    <input type="text" name="pname">
    <input type="submit" name="valider">
</form>
```

`

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to create a new record in the `responsibles` table but you are not passing in a `StudentID` value. That column is defined as `NOT NULL`, which means every row in the table should have a value for the `StudentID` column.

Comment: The studentID IS AI its should pass automatically i think

Comment: @AnassZrioual the `ResponseID` field is the auto increment field on that table, not `StudentID`

Comment: Yes u r right, i already did the relationships between them i have no idea why i still get this error

Comment: because there is no `StudentID` value being passed for the insert ... we also can't see how you are running this query ... do not put up images of code, edit your question and add the code to your question so everyone can easily access it

Comment: i made a new simple code that has same problem.

Comment: it has the same problem because it is still the same problem; you have to pass a value for that field ... you are not using a relationship in your `store` method so it isn't in play at the moment

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

In you migration try this:

```
$table->integer('StudentID ')->nullable();
$table->foreign('StudentID')->references('id')->on('student');
```

then in your console:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Comment: i dont want it to be null. I want the same value that studentid has in student table.

Comment: I already did that but the problem is i dont want it to be 0 i want the same id that i have on my student table.